# array in constructor keeps returning as null?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, constructor

```
public class sierpinski {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sierpinski s1 = new sierpinski(3);

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s1.pascal));


    }

    int row;
    String LString;
    int[] pascal;
    char[] Larray;



    public static int fact( int n) {
        int solution = 1;
        if (n == 0) {
            solution= 1;
            return solution;

        }
        else {
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                solution = solution * i;
            }

        }
        return solution;
    }

    public static int ncr( int n , int r){
        int ncr1 = fact(n)/(fact(r) * fact(n-r));
        return ncr1;
    }




    sierpinski( int row){

        this.row = row;

        char[] Larray = new char[row+1];

        int[] pascal = new int[row+1];

        for(int i =0; i < row+1; i++){

            int a = ncr(row, i);

            pascal[i] = a;


        }
        String LString = String.valueOf(Larray);

    }


}
```

im trying to do this code but pascal, keeps returning as null, when I declare it outside the constructor;
ive also tried this...

```
public class sierpinski {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sierpinski s1 = new sierpinski(3);

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s1.pascal));


    }

    int row;
    String LString;
    


    public static int fact( int n) {
        int solution = 1;
        if (n == 0) {
            solution= 1;
            return solution;

        }
        else {
            for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                solution = solution * i;
            }

        }
        return solution;
    }

    public static int ncr( int n , int r){
        int ncr1 = fact(n)/(fact(r) * fact(n-r));
        return ncr1;
    }




    sierpinski( int row){

        this.row = row;

        char[] Larray = new char[row+1];

        int[] pascal = new int[row+1];

        for(int i =0; i < row+1; i++){

            int a = ncr(row, i);

            pascal[i] = a;


        }
        String LString = String.valueOf(Larray);

    }


}
```

and I get this error

```
sierpinski.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s1.pascal));
                                            ^
  symbol:   variable pascal
  location: variable s1 of type sierpinski
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

saying it cannot find symbol, any solutions and does anyone know how to fix this??

thanks

tried declaring the variable at the top, but I have no clue how to get this to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are essentially methods.

```java
sierpinski(int row) { // this is a constructor

  this.row = row; // this sets a field.
  int[] pascal = new int[row+1]; // this creates a new local variable

  // constructor ends, and with it, all local variables GO AWAY
}
```

You want to declare a field. You already have one (`row`), and you already set it (`this.row = row`). If you want `pascal` to still exist when the constructor ends, it needs to be a field and not a local:

```
public Sierpinski {
  private int row;
  private int[] pascal;

  public Sierpinski(int row) {
    this.row = row;
    this.pascal = new int[row];
  }
}
```